# Linking tabbar items with phonegap plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Basically I am using phonegap to create an iPhone application, I am using the native controls plugin in order to integrate a native tabbar - I've got that working however I am unsure how to make it so that when each tab bar item is selected it will forward the user to a link - in the case of this application I intend to send the user to a particular div id #element. I am also attempting to use an image for the tab bar item but this does not appear to be working either...

How do I go about doing this, the code I have so far is below.

```
                                <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

                                function onBodyLoad()
                                {
                                    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
                                }

                                /* When this function is called, PhoneGap has been initialized and is ready to roll */
                                function onDeviceReady()
                                {

                                    // Initializating TabBar
                                    nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
                                    nativeControls.createTabBar();

                                    // Item 1 tab
                                    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                                                    "item1",
                                                                    "Item1",
                                                                    "/themes/images/item1@2x.png",
                                                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                                                    location.href = "#section1"
                                                                    }}
                                                                    );

                                    // Item 2 tab
                                    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                                                    "item2",
                                                                    "Item2",
                                                                    "/themes/images/item2@2x.png",
                                                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                                                    location.href = "#section2"
                                                                    }}
                                                                    );

                                    // Item 3 tab
                                    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                                                    "item3",
                                                                    "Item3",
                                                                    "/themes/images/item3@2x.png",
                                                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                                                    location.href = "#section3"
                                                                    }}
                                                                    );

                                    // Item 4 tab
                                    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                                                    "item4",
                                                                    "Item4",
                                                                    "/themes/images/item4@2x.png",
                                                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                                                    location.href = "#section4"
                                                                    }}
                                                                    );

                                    // Item 5 tab
                                    nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
                                                                    "item5",
                                                                    "Item5",
                                                                    "/themes/images/item5@2x.png",
                                                                    {"onSelect": function() {
                                                                    location.href = "#section5"
                                                                    }}
                                                                    );

                                    // Compile the TabBar
                                    nativeControls.showTabBar();
                                    nativeControls.showTabBarItems("mechanics", "materials", "waves", "electricity", "light");
                                    nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("mechanics");
                                }

                                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this tabs https://github.com/groovetrain/jQuery.mobile-Tabs#readme

Here is the fiddle on how you can do what you want to do
http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/85aUX/